# Tomcat Not running on configured port

Tags: tomcat, port, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Tomcat 5.5 on my server (windows7 R2) and i have configured it to run on port 8095 in server.xml,
but it always run on port 80. I have multiple network cards configured so i gave the ipaddress in configuration

```
<Connector port="8095"               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    address="10.0.51.30" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**netstat returned the following for the ipaddress:**

```
  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:0            LISTENING       16740

  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:51796        ESTABLISHED     16740

  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:51799        ESTABLISHED     16740

  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:51802        ESTABLISHED     16740

  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:51805        ESTABLISHED     16740

  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:51808        ESTABLISHED     16740

  TCP    10.0.51.30:80          dev-gn-04:51811        ESTABLISHED     16740
```

I'm sure 8095 port is open and no other process is using.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The config looks good to me; one issue, which may just be a copy-n-paste-to-stackoverflow thing and therefore a red herring, is that you have `&lt;Connector port="8095"`, not `<Connector port="8095"`.  In other words, the escape sequence for the less-than sign, not the actual character.  And, in your sample snippet, the closing `>` is NOT an escaped char, which makes me think that something is up, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "maxSpareThreads" attribute on the Connector. You are probably thinking of "maxThreads". I don't know how lenient Tomcat is of errors... this could be the cause or could be a red herring, but try making that change and see if it works.

My only other thought is that the default server.xml comes with multiple Connectors in it, most of them commented out but there for example purposes to give you ideas. Just, ah, make sure you're not configuring a commented-out Connector. (I've done worse, no worries.)